# Software to block non whitelisted apps from the internet on a scheduled basis

Tags: windows, firewall, windows-11

I'm looking for software that can block all apps except a whitelist from using the internet during specific times of the day.

This is to enforce user discipline. e.g. not be tempted by web browsing.

It's for me, not for any employees ) I just have a problem with spending too much time on sites like reddit. I know people might recommend extensions but I would prefer to find a system level solution for my own reasons.

I guess maybe some kind of firewall software might be able to do this?

I'm looking for free software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean "free" as in gratis, you might be able to make do with the free version of [Cold Turkey](https://getcoldturkey.com/).

It's an aggressive website blocker, and when I say "aggressive", I mean it: if you disable the companion browser extension, the main program will kill the browser outright, and while the block is active even its uninstaller will refuse to run.